# How can I simplify my nested for-loops with ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, mapreduce, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

Say I have 2 `NSDictionaries` that I don't know beforehand like:

```
NSDictionary *dictA = @{ @"key1" : @1,
                         @"key2" : @2  };

NSDictionary *dictB = @{ @"key1" : @"a string" };
```

I want to find the first match between the keys of `dictB` and the keys or values of `dictA`. Each key of `dictB` will either be a NSNumber or a string. If it's a number, try to find a match from the **values** of `dictA`. If it's a string, try to find a match from the **keys** of `dictA`.

Using for loops, it would looks something like this:

```
id match;
for (id key in dictA ) {
    for (id _key in dictB {
        if ( [_key is kindOfClass:NSNumber.class] && _key == dictA[key] ) {
            match = _key
            goto outer;
        }
        else if ( [_key is kindOfClass:NSString.class] && [_key isEqualToString:key] ) {
            match = _key
            goto outer;
        }
    }
};
outer:;

NSString *message = match ? @"A match was found" : @"No match was found";
NSLog(message);
```

How could I rewrite this with ReactiveCocoa using `RACSequence` and `RACStream` methods so it looks something like:

```
// shortened pseudo code:
// id match = [dictA.rac_sequence compare with dictB.rac_sequence using block and return first match];
```

Comment: Have you tried using `filter:`? it seems to naturally map on this scheme.

Comment: `filter:` operates on one stream, it doesn't operate on items in 2 streams/sequences recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically would like to create the cartesian product of the dictionaries and make a selection on it. There is no default operator in ReactiveCocoa that I know of that would do this for you. (In LINQ there are operators for this.) In RAC the simplest solution is to use the `scanWithStart:combine:` method to implement this operation. Once the cartesian is ready, the `filter:` and `take:1` operations will produce the sequence of your choice.

```
NSDictionary *adic = @{@"aa":@"vb", @"ab": @"va"};
NSDictionary *bdic = @{@"ba": @"va", @"bb":@"vb"};;

RACSequence *aseq = adic.rac_keySequence;
RACSequence *bseq = bdic.rac_keySequence;

RACSequence *cartesian = [[aseq scanWithStart:nil combine:^id(id running, id next_a) {
    return [bseq scanWithStart:nil combine:^id(id running, id next_b) {
        return RACTuplePack(next_a, next_b);
    }];
}] flatten];

RACSequence *filteredCartesian = [cartesian filter:^BOOL(RACTuple *value) {
    RACTupleUnpack(NSString *key_a, NSString *key_b) = value;
    // business logic with keys
    return false;
}];

RACSequence *firstMatch = [filteredCartesian take:1];
```

Comment: Very elegantly written.

Comment: @yourfriendzak This is why I love RAC. :)

Comment: I find this totally obtuse. This is why I don't love RAC. ;)

Comment: @smallduck As programmer, I find it interesting to look at different solutions to a problem. RAC, in my opinion, is taking a rather elegant way of minimizing state in your applications and expressing dependencies as chains of events/signals. Once one gets used to it, the syntax is not disturbing and the resulting code is significantly easier to handle and understand than the imperative description. You needn't use it but e.g. multithreaded programming is something that FRP and RAC has a really good angle on.